# Problem Solve - How to create a Bash script to list all variates?

Tags: bash, list

If you have a list, how would you work out all the possible variates using bash?

Example list

- One
- Two
- Three

Possible Variates

- One
- Two
- Three
- One + Two
- Two + Three
- Three + One
- One + Two + Three

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you can hardcode the list, brace expansion does cross products:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' {One,}" "{Two,}" "{Three,}
One Two Three
One Two
One  Three
One
 Two Three
 Two
  Three
```

with a trailing blank line

Or, with an array:

```sh
items=(One Two Three)
num=${#items[@]}

for ((offset = 0; offset < num; offset++)); do
    for ((length = num - offset; length > 0; length--)); do
        echo "${items[*]:offset:length}"
    done
done
```

```
One Two Three
One Two
One
Two Three
Two
Three
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a binary mask. When there's 0 at a position, don't print the corresponding element, if there's 1, print it. Add 1 to the binary mask to change what elements are printed.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -eu

variations () {
    local b=()  # The mask.
    local i
    for i ; do  # Populate the mask with zeros.
        b+=(0)
    done
    b[-1]=1     # Change the last zero to 1.

    while ((${#b[@]} < $# + 1)) ; do

        for ((i=0 ; i<$# ; ++i)) ; do
            local j
            (( j=i+1 ))
            if ((b[i])) ; then        # Print only the numbers where mask is 1.
                printf '%s ' "${!j}"  # Variable indirection.
            fi
        done
        echo

        # Add one.
        if ((b[-1] == 0)) ; then
            b[-1]=1
        else
            i=-1
            while (( b[i] )) ; do
                b[i]=0
                (( --i ))
                (( -i > ${#b[@]} )) && return
            done
            b[i]=1
        fi
    done
    return
}

variations One Two Three
```